# How can I draw or define these node styles with tikz for a flow chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I want to define node styles like this:

```
% Preamble: \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
entrada/.style={
        trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=-70,
        draw=some color, thick, fill=some color!20, text width=12em, 
        text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em
               }
```

This results in nodes like this one:
[image]

I want to do the same, but the nodes display must be similar to these:
[image]

and [image]

and
[image]

The color is not relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place to look for node shapes is chapter 71, about the `shapes` library, in the TikZ manual. The `tape` shape used for the first one here isn't quite the same as your example, but it's similar. I didn't add any colours here, but you can add a `fill` like any other node.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes.geometric, % defines cylinder shape
  shapes.symbols, % defines tape shape
  shapes.arrows % defines single arrow style
}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 A/.style={draw,
           tape,
           tape bend top=none,
           minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm
           },
 B/.style={draw,
           single arrow,
           single arrow head extend=0,
           single arrow tip angle=155,
           shape border rotate=270,
           minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm
           },
 C/.style={draw,
           cylinder,
           shape border rotate=90,
           minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm
           },
]

\node [A] {};
\node [B] at (3,0) {};
\node [C] at (6,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```